# Angular modal dialog sequence

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, sequence

Good day,

I have problem with Dialogs called in loop. There is code:

```
matches.forEach(function(entry) {
  $scope.transferEntry = _.clone(entry)
  $scope.transferEntry.ChangeCount = 1
  if (add) {
    $scope.transferEntry.Max = entry.ActualUsed != undefined && entry.ActualUsed < entry.Count ? entry.Count - entry.ActualUsed : entry.Count
  } else {
    $scope.transferEntry.Max = entry.ActualUsed
  }
  $scope.OpenModalTransfer(toArray, fromArray, add)
})
```

And I need wait for response from Modal window before next loop item.

Thank you

Comment: What modal dialog is used? Post `OpenModalTransfer` function.

Comment: `$scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/Views/Modals/HW-Transaction.html',
            scope: $scope
        })

        $scope.modalInstance.submit = function (modal) {
            if (modal.$valid == true) { .....`

Comment: This is very simple problem, but you need to provide OpenModalTransfer function.

Comment: Please, can you show how? I never use this provide...